# Selenium Servers and Geckodriver don't run at same port

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a Selenium Script (Using PHP) using a Webserver.
I'm working on Kali and to simulate the Webserver I use Xampp.
I tried to run the selenium script on Xampp by the following steps:
-Download the Php Webdriver Bindings, put them in the folder 'htdpcs' of xampp and edit the 'example.php' file following the settings of my own device.
-Download and execute the Selenium Server Standalone, on port :4444.
In the end, I download the geckodriver and I execute the file, but I got the this error:

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

How to fix it in order to run the php-selenium script?

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium Server will fork a geckodriver as soon as it needs one to start a new browser session. You should not start a geckodriver yourself. If you want to use its Webdriver API yourself you can start it with the `--webdriver-port` argument.

Comment: So I start the standalone server and then which command should I type?

Comment: Because If I just start the server and I try to run the script, it returns error